# Getting permission denied error in pycharm(Error no.13)

Tags: python, pycharm, file-handling, access-denied

While opening and reading a file in pycharm I am getting access denied error as follows.I have tried running pycharm as administrator and all security permissions are granted in that folder.

Comment: Are you maybe trying to use `open` on a folder (not a file) in Windows?

Comment: BoarGules I have tried both running file and folder. When I run folder it shows permission  denied error and when I run file it shows "no such file or directory" message. In that location there is file.There is same question here but solution is not working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50081274/i-am-recieving-a-permissionerror-errno-13-when-running-open-in-pycharm-windows please help

Comment: The code is here:- open("c:\\users\\jaypa\\Documents\\first_tex)

Comment: Sorry there is " quotes mark at last too.

Comment: Looks to me you are missing an extension. Shouldn't that be `first_tex.txt` or something. If you have Windows Explorer set up to hide known extensions (which is the default) then you can never be 100% sure what the file is really called.

Comment: BoarGules solved thank you infinite!

Comment: BoarGules can you answer my second question too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54946643/how-to-deploy-or-upload-software-on-website

Comment: Thanks for the invitation but web deployment is a big topic and I suspect your question is outside SO's remit.